# How to change searchview icon color?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar, icons, searchview

I know there's already a lot of answers for this question here, and I wouldn't be creating another thread if I hadn't already tried everything I saw here. 
Anyway, the question is pretty simple. I don't mind if the solution comes from XML styling or Java code (both solutions are welcome). I will show everything (most of it anyway) I've tried to solve it.

First of all, the searview icon seems to be immutable by code since I can't change anything from it. My searchview is declared in `menu.xml` as this

```
<item android:id="@+id/icon_search"
    android:title="Searchador"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp" <!-- icon not used by searchview anyway -->
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
/>
```

and inside my `onCreateOptionsMenu` I have this

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.icon_search);
searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
MenuTint.colorIcons(this, menu, Color.BLUE);
return true;
```

The `MenuTint.colorIcons(this, menu, Color.BLUE);` I got from a special class I found [here](https://gist.github.com/jaredrummler/ec7dfb73f3235ad8e951) where it basically changes all my icons color, unfortunately not working for the searchview icon.

I then found some answers suggesting to use a style like this

```
<style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
   <!-- changing my icon, its color and stuff.. -->
   <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/ic_search</item></style>
```

but I was getting the `No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.SearchView'.` error.

I then found that I should add the `android-support-app-compat` project library instead of just the `.jar`. It didn't work. I mean, the import worked, but the error kept showing. Then, I found somewhere that I should change the `project.properties` from target=android-19 to 21 (or higher) but it didn't solved the "No resource found" error.

So I'm pretty much stuck for this simple detail where I need to change the searchview color.

Also, this is not exactly the same question, but I believe it might be solved the in the same way so I will include here: I wanted to change distance between the icons. Someone suggested this solution

```
<style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>                  
</style>
```

but I end up getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xegJC.png)

As you can see, this approach works for my custom icons only, but not for the searchview icon, neither for the menu overflow icon. I would like to change the distance between ALL icons equally.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to change SearchView's search icon, you just need to get the image view within the view as follow:

```
searchView = v.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
//change icon color
ImageView searchIcon = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_button);
searchIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable.ic_search_icon));
```

It is important that the icon is *R.id.search_button* and you can replace it with a white vector asset that you provide, in this case *R.drawable.ic_search_icon*

Similarly, you can change the text within the SearchView as follows:

```
//set color to searchview
SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchAutoComplete = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
searchAutoComplete.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColorandroid.R.color.white));
searchAutoComplete.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
```

Answer (score 21):

For `android.x`,

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    ...

    ImageView searchIcon= 
    searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);

    // To change color of close button, use:
    // ImageView searchCloseIcon = (ImageView)searchView
    //        .findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);

    searchIcon.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary),
            android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    ...

    return true;

}
```

Comment: To add more to this very useful answer, these search_mag_icon, search_button etc in  searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon) are automatically supplied, these IDs are not defined by you. You need to choose from the available suggestions from auto complete

Comment: I'm using androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0 and the view cannot be found

Comment: If you like me are using a custom icon for the search icon, use searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_button);

Answer (score 11):

```
 final SearchView searchViewAndroidActionBar = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchViewItem);
        // change close icon color
        ImageView iconClose = (ImageView) searchViewAndroidActionBar.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
        iconClose.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
       //change search icon color
        ImageView iconSearch = searchViewAndroidActionBar.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_button);
        iconSearch.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
```

Answer (score 9):

To change the search view's icon color use the following lines of code:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchview);
ImageView icon = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_button);
icon.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can change or customize the icons of the **SearchView** by adding you're own drawable icons.

```
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:closeIcon="@drawable/close_icon"
        app:searchHintIcon="@drawable/search_icon"
        app:searchIcon="@drawable/search_icon"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below code:

```
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
Drawable dr = searchItem.getIcon();
    
dr.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

OR:

```
dr.setColorFilter(BlendModeColorFilterCompat
         .createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(Color.RED, BlendModeCompat.SRC_ATOP));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **theme** in your layout

In your **styles** file define:

```
 <style name="YourAppTheme.DarkSearchViewTheme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
 </style>
```

Then if you use **menu inflation**, you can apply this theme into your activity from the manifest

Or if you explicitly use SearcView widget in your **layout**, you can apply it into your widget by theme attribute like this:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    android:theme="@style/YourAppTheme.DarkSearchViewTheme"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Only needed answer

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
ImageView searchIcon = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_button);
searchIcon.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE);
```

If you want to change close icon color, use this one:

```
ImageView searchClose = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
searchClose.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the Drawable you want to tint, wrap it with a tinted drawable , and set it as a new one for the search menu item:

```
@JvmStatic
fun getTintedDrawable(inputDrawable: Drawable, @ColorInt color: Int): Drawable {
    val wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(inputDrawable.mutate())
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, color)
    DrawableCompat.setTintMode(wrapDrawable, Mode.SRC_IN)
    return wrapDrawable
}
```

Usage:

```
val drawable =getTintedDrawable(...)
searchMenuItem.icon = drawable
```

And this should work for all Android versions that android-x (support library) supports.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that in later (2020) appCompat scenarios I have had trouble changing icon colors, but found this one to work:

(kotlin)

```
searchItem.icon.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilterCompat.createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(Color.RED, BlendModeCompat.SRC_ATOP)
```