# How to change color of searchView's search icon color programatically inside edittext?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-search

I have SearchView in my toolbar 
and I am wondering how can I change search icon inside SearchView Edittext drawableleft icon color programatically?

```
searchView = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)?.actionView as? SearchView
```

I know using findViewById of SearchView I can find components of SearchView and do it 
But it doesn't work and I would like to know if it possible to change edittext underline color programatically?

Here is my image you can see what I mean and I have changed the close button color I want to have the same for other components

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8F6y.png)

```
val searchText = searchView?.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text) as SearchView.SearchAutoComplete
searchText.compoundDrawables[0].setTint(Color.RED)
```

Comment: Possibly your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46355969/9871059).

Comment: No it doesn't the same . it changes the search icon I need to change inside edittext search icon

Comment: Could you please make a screen or highlignt what do you need to change? Because if you just need to change the color you could use another method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work

```
val searchIcon = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_mag_icon) as ImageView
searchIcon.setColorFilter(Color.Red)
```

Answer (score 0):

I make some researches and find info that HintIcon is private field and you can't change in programmatically. I'm not sure about that but only one way that I found yet was about changing XML attribute.

```
app:searchHintIcon="@drawable/ic_search"
```

After that, the whole icon was changed so you could just create a simple search vector with a colour that is needed.

[image: SearchView Serach Hint Icon]

Probably there are other ways to change it but right now I'm not really sure.