# How do i change my search view icon color?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a search view nested inside my toolbar, and I would like to change the color of my search icon. I tried what others have suggested on StackOverflow and several blogs but it doesn't seem to fix my problem. I am not sure what to do from here. Some help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance,

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {






        ImageView searchIcon=
                searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);

        // ImageView searchCloseIcon = (ImageView)searchView
        //        .findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);

        searchIcon.setColorFilter(R.color.white);

        return true;

    }




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#111111"
    tools:context=".Controller.News_Activity">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">




    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryHint="What stock are you looking to buy?"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/animation_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/animation_view"
        android:layout_width="25sp"
        android:layout_height="30sp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: check this --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/46355969/12553303

Comment: Runtime you can change color of search icon try this searchView.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary),
            android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

Comment: I already tried both of those approaches as you can see from my code above.

Answer (score 0):

you have to find your icon from the menu and set it to that. Please find below code

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_confirm, menu);
    MenuItem search_mag_icon= menu.findItem(R.id.search_mag_icon);
    search_mag_icon.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_filter);
    Utils.menuIconColor(search_mag_icon, Color.WHITE);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater);
}


//utils method
public static void menuIconColor(MenuItem menuItem, int color) {
    Drawable drawable = menuItem.getIcon();
    if (drawable != null) {
        drawable.mutate();
        drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set background attribute for the searchview in your xml